# Entropy Balancing Did Not Create Balanced Means (R)

Tags: entropy

I am looking at how sex impacts judicial decision making and am trying to balance my dataset where my treatment variable is named "gender.judge" (0 for control group, males, and 1 for treatment group, females). I want to balance the data on these relevant variables: jcs, confirmation year, party, racial minority, and judicial experience.

By using this code, I am able to create and add weights to my dataset. However, when I use the summarize function to assess whether the balancing was successful, I am left with different weighted means in the treatment and control groups.

Why is my entropy balancing not successfully weighting the covariates?

My code:

```
library(ebal)
library(data.table)

eb <- ebalance(Treatment = abortion$gender.judge,
               X = cbind(abortion$jcs,
                         abortion$confirm.yr,
                     abortion$party.judge,
                         abortion$minority.judge, 
                     abortion$jud.experience))

#all the treated observations have weight=1 

abortion_treat <- abortion |>
  filter(gender.judge==1) |>
  mutate(weights=1)

#control observations have weight based on the entropy balancing 

abortion_con <- abortion |>
  filter(gender.judge==0) |>
  mutate(weights= eb$w)

abortion_balanced<- bind_rows(abortion_treat, abortion_con)


#Verifying that the groups were properly balanced

abortion_balanced |> 
  group_by(gender.judge) |>
  summarize(weighted.mean(jcs, weights), 
            weighted.mean(party.judge, weights), 
            weighted.mean(confirm.yr, weights), 
            weighted.mean(minority.judge, weights),
            weighted.mean(jud.experience,weights))
```

Comment: The `ebal` package is old and buggy. Try using `WeightIt` instead and assess balance with `cobalt`. There might be problems with how you manually manipulated the weights that would be avoided using the packages I recommended (which I also maintain).